# Using sscanf() in C to get a variable number of substrings

Tags: c, regex, string, scanf

So I am writing a parser in C for an assembly language.
I have macros that can either take either of the forms:

```
# label
# dat variable_name, 3
```

How can I use a single sscanf (or another method) to split the expression into the various components.

E.g. identifier (for the label and dat), variable (for the variable name) and value (for the value)

Comment: *single sscanf* - why single? A loop with `strtok` will do.

Comment: You cannot parse with `scanf`, you can only scan. Otherwise it would be `parsef`.

Comment: You can pass the string to `sscanf` and scan for the maximum number of components you expect it to contain. Then examine the return value from `sscanf` to find out how many there actually were. For example `items = sscanf(instr, "%s%s%s%s%s", s1, s2, s3, s4, s5);`. And then examine each one further.

Comment: @Jabberwocky `parsef` would be nice :)

Answer (score 1):

> How can I use a single sscanf (or another method) to split the expression into the various components.

Use `"%n"` to record the progress of scan.

```
char label_dat[10 + 1];
char var_name[20 + 1];
int var_val; 
int n1 = 0;
int n2 = 0;
//               v-------v----v---- Tolerate trailing whitespace                  
sscanf(s, "# %10s %n %20s , %d %n", label_dat, &n1, var_name, &var_val, &n2);

// If scanning made it to `n1` and there was no more text
if (n1 && s[n1] == '\0') {
  printf("Label '%s'\n", label_dat);
// If scanning made it to `n2` and there was no more text
} else if (n2 && s[n2] == '\0') {
  printf("Data '%s', Name '%s', Value %d\n", label_dat, var_name, var_val);
} else {
  puts("Bad input");
}
```

More code needed if a space after the `#` and `,` is required.

Comment: Or analyze the value returned by `sscanf()` which will tell which of the conversions (not counting `%n`) worked — there are three conversions, so a return value of 1 indicates a label, of 3 indicates a variable (data), and anything else indicates problems.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler True, yet that approach does not detect trailing junk after the _dat value_.  Of course a sentinel variable could be added.  Many ways to tackle this.  I like the `"x %n"` as it well handles formats requiring fixed text `x` after the data and allows for trailing white-space.

Comment: I didn't say "do not use any `%n` conversions".  I did suggest "use the return value from `sscanf()`", and also pointed out that the count returned doesn't include any of the `%n` specifications.  What you've suggested is close to what I was thinking of suggesting — hence an up-vote — but I would be looking at the return value of `sscanf()`.